# Moving into an office and need a router, will any do?

Tags: router

We're moving into an office. They are providing an ethernet port, and say we must buy a router.

I am looking at the linksys e1200 because it supports dd-wrt and is pretty cheap.

I think it says on the spec page it's a cable router. Would this thing be suitable? Do you plug the ethernet into the 'internet' port or into another port to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *should* work -- and yes, you would plug the Ethernet cable into the port labeled "Internet" on this router, and then another cable from one of the other ports to your computer. As with any electronic device, I recommend you purchase it from someplace where you can return it easily if it doesn't work as needed.

But ... if you only need *one* computer connected, I don't think you need a router at all: You should be able to plug that Ethernet cable directly into your computer.

I recommend you discuss this with the people who told you that you need to buy a router to make sure you don't spend money you don't have to spend.